# Linearity and how it affects the response of a system

Tags: signal, control-system, signal-processing, math, system

I've been reading Schaum's outlines for Signals and Systems, and stumbled across the beginning of impulse responses. However, I saw this:

---

[image: Schaum's outlines book]

---

Which I understood as the impulse response being "*what would happen if the input to a function f(t) was dirac(t)*". However, the next pages said this about its linearity:

---

[image: The question in mind]

---

The thing that stopped me in my tracks was looking at **Equation 2.3**, wherein the function **x(τ)** was simply taken out of the transformation. Why did that happen? Was it because it was just a constant at τ?

I always assumed that in a transformation, even if the input was a constant, it still had to undergo the transformation. Like, if the transformation **T{x(t)}** was

$$T\{x(t)\} = x^2$$

and the input would be something like **2x**, then that would mean...

$$T\{x(t)\} = T\{2x\} =  (2x)^2$$
and that
$$(2x)^2 =/= 2(x)^2$$

Is there something wrong with my thought process? Or did I misinterpret the book?

Comment: x^2 is not a linear function

Comment: @Ryan ah, shoot, yeah! Now I get it. Linear has the property of homogeneity, so c*T{x(t)} == T{c*x(t)} ! Thanks for that, I definitely overlooked that concept